# What does "Drag somebody down into your tomb" mean?

Tags: phrases

It's a phrase from **Rework** book written by **Jason Fried**. 
Here is the context:

> They want to drag others down into their tomb. If you're hopeful and ambitious, they'll try to convince you your ideas are impossible. They'll say you're wasting your time.

Comment: give more context, at least a paragraph

Comment: @MariusHancu OK

Comment: Since they think that they can't achieve much, they'll try to convince you that you can't either.

Comment: What does it mean to (figuratively) "drag someone down"?  What would it mean to drag that person into a tomb?  And why would the person doing the dragging be in a (figurative) tomb anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You should have provided a link to the book after searching Google Books say with

**"Drag” tomb jason fried rework**

which I did, which me to this link and context:

> [Rework](https://books.google.ca/books?id=U77um_h_dgcC&pg=PA13&dq=%22Drag%E2%80%9D%20tomb%20jason%20fried%20rework&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zMwjVeKCBYPGsAXU3YCoCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Drag%E2%80%9D%20tomb%20jason%20fried%20rework&f=false) - Page 13 Jason Fried, ‎David Heinemeier Hansson - 2010 -
>
> **Even worse, they want to drag others down into their tomb.**

[which is different from your quote]

**It's about pessimistic people, mentally dead already (thus in their tombs), who can't accept new ideas and want to make you the way they are - lacking originality and courage.**

Comment: I'm not a professional yet

Comment: Marius, insulting the quality of the question as part of your answer is uncalled-for.